# When do we use parallel algorithms for enumerating combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, parallel-computing, enumeration

I know that combination is used in many areas. But do we really need parallel version of algorithms for that? If so, where do they used?

Here is a famous example of parallel algorithms, [*Adaptive and Optimal Parallel Algorithms for Enumerating Permutations and Combinations*](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article-pdf/30/5/433/1046607/30-5-433.pdf) by S. G. AKL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one.
[A parallel algorithm for finding small sets of genes that are enough to distinguish two biological states](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S1415-47572004000400034&script=sci_arttext)

But if you found others, I would like to know.